# how to make the xlab coincide with its representation (barplot) in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a `.csv` file in which I have cities. Such file looks like:

```
city_name
madrid
barcelona
barcelona
madrid
sevilla
sevilla
madrid
sevilla
barcelona
palma
madrid
leon
sevilla
cadiz
sevilla
cadiz
barcelona
leon
cadiz
cadiz
barcelona
madrid
leon
leon
leon
madrid
madrid
sevilla
barcelona
palma
leon
cadiz
palma
```

I want to represent a `barplot`. This is so far what I've got:

[image]

But as you might note, `leon` does not appear 3 times but 6 (such city is `palma` instead). The barplot is correct but the `xlab` (x-axis) does not coincide with what it's represented.

My code in R-Shiny:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("cities")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  wd.datapath = paste0(getwd(), "/assets")
  wd.init = getwd();
  setwd(wd.datapath)

  d.in = read.csv("cities.csv", header = TRUE)

  cities = d.in$city_name

  unique_cities = unique(cities)

  output$cities <- renderPlot({
    barplot(table(c(cities)), names = unique(cities))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line 19 with `barplot(table(cities))`. You are using the `c()` function which basically retrieves a vector of integers and that is what R actually represents regardless of `names` argument.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("cities")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  wd.datapath = paste0(getwd(), "/assets")
  wd.init = getwd();
  setwd(wd.datapath)

  d.in = read.csv("cities.csv", header = TRUE)

  cities = d.in$city_name

  unique_cities = unique(cities)
  print(c(cities))
  output$cities <- renderPlot({
    barplot(table(cities))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How does this differ from my proposed answer to avoid use of *names* arg?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the *names* argument and have `barplot` default to the names attribute of `table` output. Whereas `table` sorts the values in alphabetical order, `unique()` returns a distinct list of values in the order presented in data.

```
cities = c("madrid", "barcelona", "barcelona", "madrid", "sevilla", "sevilla", "madrid", 
           "sevilla", "barcelona", "palma", "madrid", "leon", "sevilla", "cadiz", "sevilla", 
           "cadiz", "barcelona", "leon", "cadiz", "cadiz", "barcelona", "madrid", "leon", 
           "leon", "leon", "madrid", "madrid", "sevilla", "barcelona", "palma", "leon", "cadiz", "palma")

table(cities)
# cities
# barcelona     cadiz      leon    madrid     palma   sevilla 
#         6         5         6         7         3         6

unique(cities)
# [1] "madrid"    "barcelona" "sevilla"   "palma"     "leon"      "cadiz"  

barplot(table(cities))
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Did not work by removing `names` argument, but in line 19, I called `barplot(table(c(cities)))` instead of `barplot(table(cities))`. [Without the `c()` function]. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm...exact code here with or without `c()` should generate same exact graph. Here, *cities* should match your data frame column, *d.in$city_name*. And using `names` on unique values generates your earlier incorrect graph. I invite you to run this code in an empty R environment to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you edit your piece of code as follows it may work for you:

```
output$cities <- renderPlot({
    summary <- as.data.frame(table(c(cities)))
    barplot(summary$Freq, names = summary$Var1)
  })
```

Comment: Will not work. `xlab` (x-axis) has numerical values that are the ones generated by `c(cities)`. I want the x-axis to contain the name of each city. I already solved it, refer to my own answer. Thank you.